# Managing a simple SQL Server database table with a Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, json, sql-server, tomcat, servlets

I started a new job recently and I'm using existing programs and creating new ones based on the previous ones.
The IT team at the hospital is pretty small so it looks really homemade (their was no versioning tool before I get there).

Those servlets are working but are not state of the art in regards to proper coding. For example it's not MVC, the HTML part is inside the main class. It's enough for simply displaying results from a database from criteria.

Right now I need to manage a database: display the results, add a new line, edit lines.
I'm pretty sure it's a common need and I should be able to find some tutorials or examples but I don't.

```sql
MYTABLE
[id_config] [int] NULL,
[label] [varchar](150) NULL,
[activ] [int] NULL
```

Could someone help me?
I now I should uses JSON (I think). The thing is, I don't have much time so I'm looking for something very simple (in regard to my needs) and straightforward.

Here is a sample of one of our servlets

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
 
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
 
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
 
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat ;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.text.ParseException ;
 
 
public class monServletConfig extends HttpServlet {
 
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        doPost(request, response) ;
    }
 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {   
// Connexion BDD
 
         GenerePageConfig (connexionBDD)
        }
 
 
        private void GenerePageConfig (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Connection connexionBDD) throws Exception
    {
                id_config= request.getParameter("id_config");
        libelle = request.getParameter("libelle");
        actif=  request.getParameter("actif");
                if(bouton_valid==null)
            bouton_valid="";
 
 
// HTML page creation (not great right ?)
System.out.println("Debut HTML");
 
        out.println("<html><head>");
        out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
 
        out.println("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no'>");
        out.println("<title>"+InfoGenerales+"</title>");
 
        out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Formulaire.css'>");
        out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css?_=0db1cd38700c0cfcdc140c39a2ebc306'>");
        out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>");
        out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css'>");
        out.println("<link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' title='RSS 2.0' href='http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml'>");
 
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"../calendarDateInput.js\"></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js'></script>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js'></script>");       
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js'></script>");
 
        //paramétrage data tables
        // la ligne datatable.moment doit correspondre au format de la date dans la tableau pour pouvoir trier dessus.
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' class='init'> $(document).ready(function() {  ");
        out.println("$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY');");                
        out.println("$('#tab_recap').DataTable( {");
        out.println("dom: 'Bfrtip',"); 
        out.println("paging: false,");      
        out.println("order: [[ 5, 'asc' ]], ");  // Indique la colonne qui sera triée par défaut
        out.println("buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],");
        out.println("'language': {  'url': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/i18n/French.json' } ");
        out.println(" } ); ");
        out.println(" } ); </script>");
 
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body >");
 
               // zone de recherche
               out.println("<fieldset>");
               out.println("<div id='exForm'><form id='idform' method=post>");
               out.println("<label for='libelle '>libelle </label> <input id ='libelle ' type='text'  name='libelle '><br>");   
               out.println("</fieldset>");
 
        out.println("<input type='submit' class='button' value=\'Rechercher\' name=\'bouton_valid\'>");
        out.println("</form> </div>");
 
                if(!bouton_valid.equals("Rechercher")||libelle .equals("")) 
        {
                  // message
                }
                else
               {
                // DB request then storage in a tab:
 
                for(cptCol = 0; cptCol < nombreColonnes; cptCol++)
                {
                    out.println("<th>"+tab[0][cptCol]+"</th>");
                }
 
                out.println("</tr>");
                out.println("</thead>");
                out.println("<tbody>");
 
                for (int i = 1; i <= maxtab; i++) // parcours des lignes 
                {
                    out.println("<tr>");
                    for(cptCol = 0; cptCol < nombreColonnes; cptCol++)
                    {
                        out.println("<td>" + tab[i][cptCol] + "</td>");//lit
                    }
                    out.println("</tr>");
                }
 
                out.println("</tbody>");
                out.println("</table>");
                out.println("<br>");    
               }
 
        }
 
}
```

I really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've got your problem, but if you don't want to use a modern web framework like spring-framework, you can handle the the servlets by a simple design.

First of all develop a servlet to handle all the requests, which is your DispatcherServlet, this servlet reads the body of the requests, which are in is some format like JSON, and cast them to relative ObjectModel, then by some request parameters like "dispatch" and "handler" you can detect that which handler or business objects of your own have to be called. "dispatch" parameter is for find out method name.

Marshal the return object and write it into response OutputStream in your servlet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll start looking into it !

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to connect to a database in Java is through JDBC. See, e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc). In order for your servlets to retrieve database connections, the most easy way (apart from using `DriverManager` in every servlet) is to use a JNDI datasource. For example you can configure in the `<Context>` element of your application:

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/main" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="user" password="changeit" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest" />
```

(cf. [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_(DBCP_2)_Configurations)) and you'll be able to obtain a `javax.sql.DataSource` in your servlets using:

```java
final DataSource dataSource = InitialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/main");
```

Probably you'll want to translate the query results into a list of domain object. Using just JDBC this can become boring, so I would recommend do to add to your environment [spring-jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.4). This is a small part of Spring's software catalog, with only 4 dependencies and it will allow you to automatize many JDBC operations through a `JdbcTemplate`: cf. [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate). With a [`BeanPropertyRowMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html) you can spare a lot of programming time.

Regarding the way your servlets output data, writing a lot a `println` statements isn't elegant, is error prone, but it is very fast. I wouldn't waste too much time trying to change this, but there is a simple way of migrating `println` statements to [JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages) (you can learn about JSP [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm)): look at the code of Tomcat's [HTMLManagerServlet](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/68991aac79a497dff9882efe3082d099ec79d222/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/HTMLManagerServlet.java):

- the oldest method [list](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/68991aac79a497dff9882efe3082d099ec79d222/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/HTMLManagerServlet.java#L339) uses a bunch of `print` statements,
- the newer methods, like [doSessions](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/68991aac79a497dff9882efe3082d099ec79d222/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/HTMLManagerServlet.java#L851), just generate the necessary data, call [`ServletRequest#setAttribute`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) and forward the request to a JSP page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll start looking into it !